# Importrange won't allow multiple imports of the same column from different files

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We're having the following issue in Google Sheets: we have a couple dozen contributors, each from a different business unit, inputting data in different copies of the exact same file. We want to use *importrange* to query the same column for each copy of the excel file, into a master file. So basically, we need to import several times "column G2:57" indifferent columns. But this seems to break the formula, as each new formula seems to believe that it is overwriting the next one and throws and error prompt.

Is there a workaround, or a part of the formula I'm missing?

I was expecting that each instances of =importrange would import and keep updated column G in a different column. I tried wit =Query({importrange("link 1":"tab!G2:57"); importrange("link 2":"tab!G2:57")}), but this tries to import both columna into the same one.

Comment: better provide a demo which reproduce the issue you have mentioned.

Comment: my best guess is, you didn't authorize the ```importrange()``` function yet so they all show up as ```#Ref```? open an empty sheet in the same spreadsheet, put down each of the ```importrange()``` with each link to authorize them one by one maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference `G2:57` does not point to column `G` but to rows `2:57` of *all* columns to the right of column `G` inclusive. To refer to rows `2:57` column `G`, use `G2:G57`.

To make your formula work, try something like this:

```
={ 
  importrange("link 1", "tab!G2:G57"), 
  importrange("link 2", "tab!G2:G57"), 
  importrange("link 3", "tab!G2:G57") 
}
```

This formula will import the three columns side by side.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, this was the issue.